# Is it possible for Apache POI to add / remove watermark to Microsoft Word

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Is it possible to add / remove image watermark to Microsoft Word 2010 by Apache POI?
Should I treat it as normal image or any special handling?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create watermarks. See the [api docs for XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.html). There is a method there called `createWatermark`. Yet this is only for text watermarks.

Comment: I have look at the api of createWatermark, is it a "image watermark" function or just a "text watermark" function?
And how about watermark removal?

Comment: I noted that it's only for creation and is only for text unfortunatelly (i did edit my anwser some time ago). There is this other SO question, that you can have a look at - in the description there is code for adding an image watermark: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12542923/how-to-set-watermark-image-at-background-in-excel-using-poi.